# Update Product Data in Analytics Ecommerce reports

Tags: google-analytics

Some time ago I have implemented Google Analytics Advanced Ecommerce using GTM DataLayer.

After year of usage we have decided to change Naming of products and Added categories/brands for each transaction, also was changed all SKU/ID.

But nothing changed in reports. Names of all old products still remains old, no Brand/Category included in reports.

How can I update Product Data in reports and add categories/brands?

Thanks!

PS New products seems to be OK, but also no Category/Brand.

Here is example of DataLayer:

```js
// Product Details 
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',
    'detail': {
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Tetris', // Name or ID is required.
        'id': 'g395',
        'sku': 'g395',
        'category': 'Toys &amp; Games',
        'brand': 'Mojo-jojo!'
      }]
    }
  }
});
//// Transaction

dataLayer.push({
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "checkout": {
      "actionField": {
        "step": 4
      }
    },
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id": 13202,
        "affiliation": "www.mojo-jojo.com",
        "revenue": 0.01
      },
      "products": [{
        "id": "g105",
        "sku": "g105",
        "name": "Duracell AA",
        "brand": "Mojo-jojo!",
        "category": "Accessories",
        "price": 0.7,
        "quantity": 1
      }]
    }
  },
  "transactionId": 13202,
  "transactionTotal": 0.01,
  "transactionProducts": [{
    "id": "g105",
    "sku": "g105",
    "name": "Duracell AA",
    "brand": "Mojo-jojo!",
    "category": "Accessories",
    "price": 0.7,
    "quantity": 1
  }],
  "event": "transaction",
  "product_ids": [105],
  "num_items": 1,
  "conversion_value": 0.01
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics data is read only.  As soon as the data is inserted you can not change it / updated.

However now that you have changed it any data being inserted from now on will contain the new names.

Comment: Few weeks passed with new data - nothing changed. If old product is ordered - old name is showing in Reports. Also no data in Categories/Brands reports...